# Configure parserOptions or parser package for ESLint and Airbnb typescript setup

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb, prettier-eslint

In my [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com) (React) project I am using [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org). I need to setup ESLint and have to use [eslint-config-airbnb-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript)

I am also using Prettier:
`prettier` (comes with Gatsby), and I installed the following packages:

```
npm install eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-prettier --save-dev
```

If I look at the documentation of [eslint-config-airbnb-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript), I don't see anything about the [@typescript-eslint/parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/parser) package?

They showing an example like:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['airbnb-typescript'],
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  }
};
```

What's the correct way? And in their example, you don't have to use the `@typescript-eslint/parser` package?

My ESLint config `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    __PATH_PREFIX__: true,
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint', 'prettier'],
  extends: [
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/react',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'error',
      {
        endOfLine: 'auto',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

My `tsconfig.js`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "esnext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "es2017"],
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I set it up in [eslint-config-auto](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/eslint-config-auto), which automatically configures eslint based on your package.json config.

```
overrides: [
  {
    files: ['**.ts', '**.tsx'],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
      project: './tsconfig.json',
    },
  },
],
```